# Can $watch listen the props in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Can $watch listen the props in Vue.js?

I test in my lab, find  I can not watch the props:

in my index.vue:

```
<test-com :data="pass_data"></test-com> 

...

export default {

  data(){
    return {
      pass_data: {a:'a', b:'b'}
      ...
    }
  }

  methods: {
    add_select_data(){
      this.pass_data.c = 'c'
      console.log('add c')   // there add the `c`
    }
  }
```

I have a button in index.vue to invoke the `add_select_data`.

in my `<test-com>`

```
<script>

  export default{
    props: {
      pass_data: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    }
    ,
    data(){
      return {
        msg: 'hello vue',
        edit_form_data: {}
      }
    },
    components: {},
    watch:{
      pass_data(new_obj, old_obj) {
        console.log(new_obj, 'ok')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I tried to watch the pass_data, but I find I can't.

Some friend can tell me how to archive this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a [`deep: true`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) option to your watcher to watch for changes in nested values of an object as below

```
watch:{
  pass_data:{
    deep: true,
    handler: function(new_obj, old_obj) {
      console.log(new_obj, 'ok')
    }
   }
}
```

But to add new reactive properties and want the watch to trigger you should use `vm.$set()`. Refer [Reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

```
add_select_data(){
  this.$set(this.pass_data, 'c' , 'c');
  console.log('add c')   // there add the `c`
}
```

Here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5oj6any/18/) demonstrating the above example

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data to be reactive to watch a new property, use this syntax to set it `this.$set(this.pass_data, 'c', 'c')` , this way it should trigger a change event. Otherwise you can test if the prop is watched by changing `this.pass_data.b = 'asd'`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

To answer your question, props can be watched just like normal data property

Comment: If you do `this.pass_data.b = 'asd'` without `deep:true` the watcher will not be triggered. See https://jsfiddle.net/c5oj6any/19/